# XLWT converting to excel file

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

In my application i'm trying to write the data to excel file using xlwt.

**Source code:**

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import sys,os
    from xlwt import Workbook, easyxf, Formula
    #define the extension
    print """Extension supported: xls, xlsx, ods"""
    ext=raw_input("Extension: ")

    def export2excel():
        '''Edit the OK.txt file to add new lines following the upper lines 
           '''
        fp = file('~/OK.txt')
        lines = fp.readlines()

        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.add_sheet('Test')
        ulstyle = easyxf('font: underline single')
        r = 0
        for line in lines:
            tokens = line.strip().split('\t')
            if len(tokens) != 21:
                continue
            for c,t in enumerate(tokens):
                for dtype in (int,float):
                    try:
                        t = dtype(t)
                    except:
                        pass
                    else:
                        break 
                ws.write(r,c+0,t)

            r += 1
        a=wb.save("file." + ext)
        print 'File exported in ' + os.getcwd()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        export2excel()
```

The file called **OK.txt** contains:

```
1   Nahant  0   2011    -70.955000  42.255000   24.0    24.0    0.00632 18.0    2.31    0   0.538   6.575   65.2    4.0900  1   296 15.3    396.90  1
2   nahant  0   2011    -70.966000  42.599281   24.0    24.0    0.00634 17.0    2.12    0.1 12.2    6.571   61.2    3.0100  1   926 19.3    391.09  2
```

There are 20 columns. When i delete a column or i delete a value there is nothing. Blank sheet.

Comment: Does it help if you remove the if len(tokens) != 21: continue ?

Comment: This line is never going to be true: `for dtype in (int, float):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line :-

```
if len(tokens) != 21:
     continue
```

skips the loop if there are 21 columns. See if removing it helps.